# Is NextJS Running Pages and Components On Server or Browser, or Both?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page in NextJS..

```
function MyPage({ props }) {
    console.log('page')
    return (<>
        <MyComponent />
    </>)
}
```

And a component...

```
export function MyComponent() {
    console.log('component')
    return (
        <>
            
        </>
    );
}
```

When I run yarn dev and browse to http://localhost:3000

I get the following logs in both the terminal and the browser console window...

```
page
component
```

This makes 0 sense. Server pages should not render on the browser. And components should not render on the server.

So my questions are...

1. What is happening here?
2. How do I tell if a component/page is a server 'thing' or a dynamic component for sure? (I seem to be mistaken here)

Answer (score 1):

These both are client-side rendering.
For server-side rendering, you'll need to use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

The props generated from this function will be managed and computed on the server and then returned to the browser. Console logs added in `getServerSideProps` will not be visible in the browser.

For example:

```
function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {

  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  console.log("SSR component")
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you can use

```
typeof window === 'undefined'
```

Explanation you can find on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598971/whats-the-purpose-of-if-typeof-window-undefined)

For example,

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // Only run on server
}

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // Only run in browser
}
```